# Change temporary table to table varible using sqlserver 2012

Tags: loops, sql-server-2012

I want to remove the #temp1 from my query and use it as another table varible that work same as it is working using #temp1 table.
Here is my query

```
DROP TABLE #temp1
;WITH cteSales AS(
    SELECT BillDate,
           BillNo,
           '-' AS     NarrationNumber,
           TotalAmount,
           0       AS ReceivedAmount
    FROM   SalesMaster
    WHERE  SalesMaster.ClientID = @ClientID
           AND SalesMaster.BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Date]  AS BillDate,
           SalesAccount.BillNo,
           SalesAccount.NarrationNumber,
           0       AS TotalAmount,
           Amount  AS ReceivedAmount
    FROM   SalesAccount
           LEFT JOIN SalesMaster sm
                ON  sm.BillNo = SalesAccount.BillNO
    WHERE  sm.ClientID = @ClientID
           AND sm.BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
), cteFormattedSales AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BillNo ASC, BillDate ASC) AS RowNum,
           *
    FROM   cteSales
)

SELECT cfs1.RowNum,
       cfs1.BillDate,
       cfs1.BillNo,
       cfs1.NarrationNumber,
       cfs1.TotalAmount,
       cfs1.ReceivedAmount,
       (cfs1.TotalAmount - cfs1.ReceivedAmount) AS DueAmount INTO #temp1
FROM   cteFormattedSales cfs1
DECLARE @BillDate date,
        @PrevBillNo INT,
        @NextBillNo INT,
        @NarrationNumber VARCHAR(15),
        @TotalAmount DECIMAL(18, 2),
        @ReceivedAmount DECIMAL(18, 2),
        @NextDue DECIMAL(18, 2),
        @PrevDue DECIMAL(18, 2)
DECLARE @finalTable TABLE(
            BillDate date,
            BillNo INT,
            NarrationNumber NVARCHAR(15),
            TotalAmount DECIMAL(18, 2),
            ReceivedAmount DECIMAL(18, 2),
            DueAmount DECIMAL(18, 2)
        )

DECLARE @TotalRecords        INT,
        @Counter             INT = 1,
        @CarryOverAmount     DECIMAL(18, 2)

SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(*)
FROM   #temp1

SELECT @BillDate = t.BillDate,
       @PrevBillNo          = t.BillNo,
       @NarrationNumber     = t.NarrationNumber,
       @TotalAmount         = t.TotalAmount,
       @ReceivedAmount      = t.ReceivedAmount,
       @PrevDue             = t.DueAmount
FROM   #temp1 t
WHERE  t.RowNum = @Counter

WHILE @Counter <= @TotalRecords
BEGIN
    SELECT @BillDate = t.BillDate,
           @NextBillNo          = t.BillNo,
           @NarrationNumber     = t.NarrationNumber,
           @TotalAmount         = t.TotalAmount,
           @ReceivedAmount      = t.ReceivedAmount,
           @NextDue             = t.DueAmount
    FROM   #temp1 AS t
    WHERE  t.RowNum = @Counter

    IF (@Counter = 1)
        SET @CarryOverAmount = @TotalAmount

    SET @PrevDue = @CarryOverAmount - @ReceivedAmount

    IF @PrevBillNo <> @NextBillNo
    BEGIN
        SET @PrevBillNo = @NextBillNo
        SET @CarryOverAmount = @TotalAmount + @PrevDue
        SET @PrevDue = 0
    END

    INSERT INTO @finalTable
      (
        BillDate,
        BillNo,
        NarrationNumber,
        TotalAmount,
        ReceivedAmount,
        DueAmount
      )
    VALUES
      (
        @BillDate,
        @PrevBillNo,
        @NarrationNumber,
        @TotalAmount,
        @ReceivedAmount,
        CASE 
             WHEN @NarrationNumber = '-' THEN @CarryOverAmount
             ELSE @PrevDue
        END
      )

    IF @PrevBillNo = @NextBillNo
    BEGIN
        IF @Counter > 1
        BEGIN
            SET @CarryOverAmount = CASE 
                                        WHEN @NarrationNumber = '-' THEN @CarryOverAmount 
                                             + @PrevDue
                                        ELSE @CarryOverAmount - @ReceivedAmount
                                   END
        END
    END

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END 
SELECT *
FROM   @finalTable
```

Here the code that i get error on invalid ReceivedAmount

```
SELECT @BillDate = t.BillDate,
           @PrevBillNo          = t.BillNo,
           @NarrationNumber     = t.NarrationNumber,
           @TotalAmount         = t.TotalAmount,
           @ReceivedAmount      = t.ReceivedAmount,
           @PrevDue             = t.DueAmount
    FROM   @Temp1 t
    WHERE  t.RowNum = @Counter

    WHILE @Counter <= @TotalRecords
    BEGIN
        SELECT @BillDate = t.BillDate,
               @NextBillNo          = t.BillNo,
               @NarrationNumber     = t.NarrationNumber,
               @TotalAmount         = t.TotalAmount,
               @ReceivedAmount      = t.ReceivedAmount,
               @NextDue             = t.DueAmount
        FROM   @Temp1 AS t
        WHERE  t.RowNum = @Counter
```

Comment: As you already have examples of table variable in the query I don't understand your question? Just do the same as those?

Comment: @Allan ,I did the same but i am only getting a single row while using Table Varible instead of #temp1 so need help to get all those data using table variable

Comment: Can you explain to us the reason why you would rather use a *table variable* than a *temporary table*?

Comment: @TT, I want to use above query in my tableadapter to create report so while using temporary table it gives error invalid name #temp1 so i am trying without using temporary table.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary: Debug it before the lines with error. What `select * from @temp1` returns? Maybe some typo?

Comment: @Inaz thanks for your reply i will try and get it done but the select * from temp1 returns the exact query what i needed but don't know what is happening after that step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do just 3 steps:

A. DECLARE table variable

```
-- correct types of columns
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE(
    RowNum int
    ,BillDate datetime
    ,BillNo int
    ,NarrationNumber int
    ,TotalAmount money
    ,RecievedAmount money
    ,DueAmount   money
)
```

B. Rewrite SELECT ... INTO -> INSERT INTO .. SELECT

```
INSERT INTO @temp1
SELECT cfs1.RowNum,
       cfs1.BillDate,
       cfs1.BillNo,
       cfs1.NarrationNumber,
       cfs1.TotalAmount,
       cfs1.ReceivedAmount,
       (cfs1.TotalAmount - cfs1.ReceivedAmount) AS DueAmount 
FROM   cteFormattedSales cfs1   
... etc ...
```

C. Replace all #temp1 to @temp1

Comment: Getting error Invalid Column name ReceivedAmount though i have receivedamount column in it

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary: on which line? Can you edit your post with new code ?

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary Ingaz explained to you the basics of what you need to do to change the temporary table to a table variable. Surely you can take his sound advice (step A, B & C) and change the script yourself?

Comment: @TT i have tried as Ingaz explained and still getting that error though column is present thank u

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary What I meant to say is, forget the queries Ingaz wrote. Only focus on the three steps he wrote down: `A. DECLARE table variable`, `B. Rewrite SELECT ... INTO -> INSERT INTO .. SELECT`, `C. Replace all #temp1 to @temp1`. Take his queries as examples on how to do this, don't simply copy/paste them. Use them as examples on how to do A, B & C. GL!

Comment: @Ingaz thank u very much it work like a charm for me. It was the example that i was always looking for

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary If the answer helped you solve your problem, you can also thank the person by accepting the answer. You can do this by checking the checkmark at the top left of the answer. You can also upvote by clicking the up-arrow at the top left of the answer.